# C - Why am I getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm a bit confused on segmentation faults apparently since I don't understand why I'm getting one. I'm trying to traverse a tree that I have built which I have tested and works fine. But, when I try to run the following function I get a segmentation fault. Any can tell me where and why I'm getting a segmentation fault so that I can avoid that in the future? Thanks.

```
void traverse(Node *root)
{
    Node *pointer;
    Node *pre;

    if(root == NULL)
        return;

    pointer = pre;

    while(pointer != NULL)
    {
        if(pointer->leftChild != NULL)
            pointer = pointer->rightChild;
        else
        {
            pre = pointer->leftChild;

            while(pre->rightChild != NULL && pre->rightChild != pointer)
                pre = pre->rightChild;

            if(pre->rightChild != NULL)
            {
                pre->rightChild = pointer;
                pointer = pointer->leftChild;
            }
            else
            {
                pre->rightChild = pointer;
                pointer = pointer->leftChild;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: you never initialize `pointer` or `pre`, and basically totally ignore the `root` node you pass in as an argument, so you'er trying to dereference pointers in undefined/uninitialized structures.

Comment: Also on line 13 you are checking if the left node is NULL and then you access the right node.

Comment: In C always properly initialise any Variable the code will read before it had been written to.

Comment: Also a debugger definitely could help drilling down to at least the line where the code crashed.

Comment: Thanks for all your input guys. I initialized the pointer and pre to null, but I'm still getting segmentation fault.

Comment: @user3713899 A segmentation fault is basically the C equivalent of a Null-Pointer exception. Dereferencing a NULL pointer is a classic cause of a segfault.

Answer (score 3):

The pointers initially contain the garbage value as you are not initialing it in your code.

```
Node *pointer;
Node *pre;
```

Since they contain garbage value, they may not point to `NULL` and where they would be pointing would be allocated to some other resources, which cannot be accessed causing segmentation fault in following line.

```
if(pointer->leftChild != NULL)
        pointer = pointer->rightChild;
```

You need to either initialize your pointers or assign to it input argument.

Edit

One more problem i could observe in your code is at `if-else` condition.
In your `if` condition, you are checking `if(pointer->leftChild != NULL)`
so if this condition is `false` (i.e. `pointer->leftChild = NULL`), you will fall into `else` block, where you are assigning like this;

```
pre = pointer->leftChild; // Here pre is always NULL
```

So if you will try to use it further, it will throw exception hence makes your code to crash.

Comment: Thanks. I initialized pointer = root and pre = NULL. But, I'm still getting the fault.

Comment: Can you post the code which is calling this function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize `Node *pre = NULL;` and `Node *pointer = root;`. You did not initialize `pre` but assigned `pointer = pre;`.

Apart form this you should change this:

```
if ( pointer->rightChild!= NULL)
           // ^^^^^^^^^^ change leftChild to rightChild 
    pointer = pointer->rightChild;
```

If the nodes of a tree have no pointer to the parent node, it is typically used a recursive function to traverse through the tree:

```
void traverse( Node *root )
{
    if ( root == NULL )
        return;

    traverse( root->leftChild );

    // do somethig with root

    traverse( root->rightChild );
}
```

Note the parameter of the recursive function takes the place of the stack which is necessary to go back from a leaf node to the root node.